# (PHP OpenServer) Код, написанный на моём редакторе, отличается от отображаемых исходников на сайте

Tags: php, вёрстка, openserver

Для примера возьмём блок, в который пользователь кидает свои файлы. Я убрал у него селектор `height`, но на странице у него всё равно стоит в стилях `height:134px`, которого в файле нет. Я решил проверить и в *Проводнике* содержание файла стилей, но там тоже отображено, что никакой высоты для блока не установлено. Я перезагрузил сервер, заново открыл проект, но ничего не помогает.

Comment: Значит не в том файле меняете. Либо кеш. Либо стиль из внешнего css. Без деталей невозможно понять, сами же понимаете.

Comment: Я решил в таком случае строго установить нулевое значение вместе с !important для теста, но и это не сработало. Я открыл этот файл в браузере в Source Panel, но там стоит height:134px.

Comment: "но там стоит height:134px" - где "там"? Если вы наводите на элемент, то справа в стилях должен быть указан файл стилей, откуда это значение берется. Или же эти 134 - сгенерированное (calculated) значение для текущего layout. Приведите пример: код, картинку.

Comment: Да, я навожу на элемент и справа были стили, откуда и берётся значение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Браузер кэширует скрипты\стили, и подставляет данные из кэша вместо получения актуальных данных с сервера, откройте сайт через режим инкогнито браузера, и проверьте.
Бороться с этим можно разными способами, например дописывать в link rel и script src после .js какой-то опциональный параметр, например timestamp, чтобы получалось `<script src="/app.js?162398476286" />` тогда браузер будет считать, что это новый файл, и будет всегда подтягивать актуальные данные, либо говорить браузеру не кешировать данные через  тег.

Comment: Я очистил кэш на своём браузере и это действительно заработало. Теперь вебсайт будет обновляться в точности с такими изменениями, как указано на моих исходниках. Спасибо вам огромное!